# jQuery select multiple attributes and check/uncheck another checkbox

Tags: jquery

How I can identify following checkboxes in different rows and check/uncheck them separately.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="F" name="eph-ds[2457][]">
<input type="checkbox" value="PR" name="eph-ds[2457][]">
<input type="checkbox" value="DPH" name="eph-ds[2457][]">
<input type="checkbox" value="F" name="eph-ds[2450][]">
<input type="checkbox" value="PR" name="eph-ds[2450][]">
<input type="checkbox" value="DPH" name="eph-ds[2450][]">
```

where [number] is dinamically created.

Example: If "F" is checked, uncheck "PR". If "PR" is checked, uncheck "F". If "DPH" is checked, uncheck all.

```
    $(":checkbox").change(function() {
    var current = this.value;
    if (current == "F") {
$(":checkbox[value=PR]").prop("checked", false);
    } 
        if (current == "PR") {
$(":checkbox[value=F]").prop("checked", false);

    } 
  if (current == "DPH") {
$(":checkbox[value=F]").prop("checked", false);
$(":checkbox[value=PR]").prop("checked", false);

    } 
});
```

This code is working, but if I deselect checkbox in the second row, then checkbox in first row will be unchecked too:

[image]

Comment: Why not just add a ID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do what you have requested:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVLAd/)</kbd>

```
var $this,num,val;

$('input[name^="eph-ds["]').click(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    num = $this.attr('name').split('[')[1].replace("]", "");
    val = $this.val();
    if (val=="F"){
        $('input:checkbox[name="eph-ds['+num+'][]"][value="PR"]').prop('checked',false);
    }else if (val=="PR"){
        $('input:checkbox[name="eph-ds['+num+'][]"][value="F"]').prop('checked',false);
    }else if (val=="DPH"){
        $('input:checkbox[name="eph-ds['+num+'][]"]').not($this).prop('checked',false);
    }
});
```

Notes:

1. Variables declared at top so they need not be re-declared with each checkbox click
2. jsFiddle adds disabling F and PR when DPH is checked (*otherwise after checking the DPH box user can THEN check either PR or F*).
3. Not necessary to query your checkboxes as groups (as suggested by previous responder)
4. If difficult to follow, this line can be broken up into three lines:
   `num = $this.attr('name').split('[')[1].replace("]", "");`

`name = $this.attr('name');     //returns eph-ds[####][]`
`temp = name.split('[')[1];     //returns ####]` 
`num = temp.replace("]", "");   //removes trailing ]`

Answer (score 4):

The API example uses quotes to fix this problem.

```
$("input[name='eph-ds[2457][]'][value='PR']").prop("checked", false);
```

And to select all of them regardless of the dynamic number, use `attr^=value`

```
$("input[name^='eph-ds['][value='PR']").prop("checked", false);
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("input[name=eph-ds[2457][]],input[value=PR]").prop("checked", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the checkboxes in order to be able to query them as groups, I simplified your markup to this:

```
<div class="row">
   <input type="checkbox" value="F" name="eph-ds[2457][]">F<br/>
   <input type="checkbox" value="PR" name="eph-ds[2457][]">PR<br/>
   <input type="checkbox" value="DPH" name="eph-ds[2457][]">DPH<br/>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <input type="checkbox" value="F" name="eph-ds[2450][]">F<br/>
   <input type="checkbox" value="PR" name="eph-ds[2450][]">PR<br/>
   <input type="checkbox" value="DPH" name="eph-ds[2450][]">DPH<br/>
</div>
```

you can still add your labels and whatever dom elements you have for your styling and structure, but the important is to have a wrapper (div.row in my case)

Now use the following script:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(":checkbox").change(function(){
                // get the wrapper so it won't affect the checkboxes in other rows
                var _parent_row = $(this).closest(".row");
                // get the checkbox value
                var _value = $(this).val();

                // uncheck PR if F is checked
                if(_value == "F" && $(this).isChecked())
                {
                    var _pr = $(_parent_row).find(":checkbox[value='PR']");
                    _pr.uncheck();
                }

                // uncheck F if PR is checked
                if(_value == "PR" && $(this).isChecked())
                {
                    var _f = $(_parent_row).find(":checkbox[value='F']");
                    _f.uncheck();
                }

                // uncheck All if DPH is checked
                if(_value == "DPH" && $(this).isChecked())
                {
                    var _f = $(_parent_row).find(":checkbox[value='F']");
                    var _pr = $(_parent_row).find(":checkbox[value='PR']");
                    _f.uncheck();
                    _pr.uncheck();
                }
            })
        })

        // prototype function to test if a checkbox is checked
        $.fn.isChecked = function(){
            return $(this).is(':checked');
        };

        // prototype function to check a textbox
        $.fn.check = function(){
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
        };

        // prototype function to uncheck a textbox
        $.fn.uncheck = function(){
            $(this).attr('checked', false);
        };
    </script>
```

This should do it :) 
You can still use the .isChecked(), .check() and .uncheck() on any other checkbox in your document (so you won't have to repeat yourself)

Answer (score 1):

check this [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kQ7LP/1/)

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="row">
   <input type="checkbox" value="F" name="eph-ds[2457][]">F<br/>
   <input type="checkbox" value="PR" name="eph-ds[2457][]">PR<br/>
   <input type="checkbox" class="clear" value="DPH" name="eph-ds[2457][]">DPH<br/>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <input type="checkbox" value="F" name="eph-ds[2450][]">F<br/>
   <input type="checkbox" value="PR" name="eph-ds[2450][]">PR<br/>
   <input type="checkbox" class="clear" value="DPH" name="eph-ds[2450][]">DPH<br/>
</div>
```

**JQuery** code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.row .clear').change(function(){
        clearFunction($(this).parent('.row'));
        $(this).prop("checked",false);
    });


    $('.row input:checkbox').change(function(){
        $(this).siblings('input').prop("checked", false);
    });
}); 
    function clearFunction(localEl){
        localEl.children('input:checkbox').each(
            function(){
                if($(this).prop('checked')){
                    $(this).removeAttr('checked');
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

did this in 10 minutes

[please check it out my minimalist approch](http://jsfiddle.net/S6D4M/)

```
<div>
<input type='checkbox' class='mEx cBox' name='F' title='F'/>
<input type='checkbox' class='mEx cBox' name='PR' title='PR'/>
<input type='checkbox' class='Ex cBox' name='DPH' title='DPH'/>
</div>

$('.cBox').change(function(){
    var current = $(this);
    var parentCntr = current.parent();
    var isChecked = current.is(':checked');
    if(isChecked) {        
        if(current.hasClass('Ex')) {
            $('.mEx',parentCntr).attr({checked:false,disabled:true});
        }else if(current.hasClass('mEx')) {
            $('.mEx',parentCntr).attr({checked:false});
            current.attr({checked:true});
        }    
    }else{
        if(current.hasClass('Ex')) {
            $('.mEx',parentCntr).attr({disabled:false});
        }
    }
});
```

I think that the required behaviour of chekboxes has nothing to do with thier values